# Using Arduino with through beam sensor on combine harvester

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a project where I'm trying to capture the output from a through beam sensor (infra red) installed on a combine harvester. I'm not much of an electronics wiz but was hoping it was going to be simple to capture the output from this sensor whilst not interfering with the operation of the sensor as far as the combine harvesters electronics were concerned.

The receiver component of the sensor has 3 wires, ground, 12v supply and output (sensor) lead. If the receiver can see the transmitter the voltage on the sensor wire is 5v when it cant see the transmitter its voltage is 1.5v. Strangely if I remove the sensors from the combine and power them on the test bench, the sensor will pass the powered voltage i.e if supplied with 12v then the receiver will pass 12v on the sensor wire if it can see the transmitter. I think the combine electronics are doing some trickery way beyond my understanding BUT that's fine, all I want to do is capture the pulse from the sensor and pass it to an Arduino without interfering with the combines electronics.

I have tried a couple of setups to no avail this is my last attempt but I cant get a signal from the sensor. I'm not sure the diode (D1) is required but as I had it I added it. In a test environment I can add 5v through R2 and the PC817 triggers and I pick a pulse up on the Arduino. All grounds are linked and the Arduino is powered from the 12v coming from the ecu.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBLREb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is there a clever bit of circuit or component which I can use to steal the pulse from the through beam whilst not interfering with its operation as far as the combines systems are concerned?

Any help appreciated with regards to how to properly design a circuit and how to make this work. I have been reading about op amps but not sure that will sort the problem.

Comment: The diode should not be needed, since the optocoupler has already an LED on that side incorporated, which is also a diode. Are you sure, that the signal pin can provide the needed current for the optocoupler? The resistor would cap the current at about 18mA, but can the signal pin provide that? You write, that the Arduino is powered from the Combine ECU and the grounds are also connected. Why do you want to use an optocoupler then? For keeping the voltage down a 5V zener diode and a resistor in series would be easier I think.

Comment: Thanks chrisl. To be honest I don't have a clue whether the signal pin can supply the power. I suspect not as I cant get any reading. Would the zenor diode circuit take less power? you wouldn't have a basic schematic on how to wire one up so I could give it a go?